# Broken Dryer - won't start

Tags: dryer

So this morning I went to put my wash into the dryer, and it didn't start.  First I checked the door switch, and it clicked on and off when pushed, so that seems to be ok.  Next I checked the breaker and outlet (with a multi-meter - yes it's eletric), and the power to the plug is fine.
When I push the start button there is a faint 'clicking' so I believe that the power into the dryer is fine, and it is a problem on the inside of the unit.

Does anyone have any suggestions on things I should start checking when I take the thing apart?  Is there a common fail that is easy to find/fix?

Comment: Don't be sure the power's fine ... years ago, I replaced a dryer because it'd spin but not dry; it turns out that one of the two fuses for the 220V circuit had failed, so the heating didn't work, but everything else did.  (I've since gotten an electrician in to change over to circuit breakers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "click" is the exact same behavior that I had last month - caused by a blown heating element. It was difficult for me to remove and replace, but easy enough to find both ends (and I'm sure this varies based on your model) and do a continuity test on it. Mine didn't conduct, so it was clear that was the problem.

Comment: it was not the heating element, but while checking for this I found the true problem, it was a snapped belt, hidden under a lot of loose lint in-side the box. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

If you open up where the electronics are you may find a schematic diagram inside. I did on mine, which was very helpful for locating a blown fuse. There are several appliance DIY repair sites that have great information. Do a Google search on your exact model and you may get lucky.